# Detect motion in live MJPEG file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ip-camera, mjpeg

I'm trying to program an application for an IP camera of mine. I want it to be able to take the IP address of the camera and detect motion (a change of a certain number of pixels in a certain space). I really have no idea how I'm going to go about this, and I can't find many tutorials. A lot of them are node.js, and the other ones use APIs or external libraries. I do not use APIs or any other external code. (I know it's a bit weird, but I have my reasons) I'm very sorry that this question probably wasn't the best, but I've been trying to find info on how to do this kind of thing and I can't find much on the web. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Some were confused as to whether I was using node.js. I'm using browser-based javascript.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: I added an edit to the origional post

Comment: The standard library in node is deliberately small, and it's expected to use external libraries for a variety of tasks. Image processing is a pretty massive undertaking to attempt without any dependencies at all. Are you sure there's no way you can rely on any external modules?

Comment: I'm not using node, I'm using browser-based javascript. But this was still helpful. Anyway, I'll usually only use external modules if I truly have to.

Comment: @TylerSelden Ah, apologies! Clearly I didn't quite read your question thoroughly enough.

Comment: All I can say is the Image is always an Image whether in Javascript or anything - So I'm not sure you cant find anything about Image Processing. Did yu try anything?? Have you pulled two images together?? then you subtract and thats your Diference!!

Comment: @gpasch whenever I look up javascript image processing it brings up tutorials on how to add filters to images and how to crop them

Comment: Ok this is a good thing https://doctorcodetutorial.blogspot.com/2019/11/learn-image-processing-using-javascript.html I dont know if it's html5 or whatever - it shows us how to access the Piiiiixles - and we go from There!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use image moments to estimate motion between images.
Some CS reading about it ( or google it up ):
https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82353641.pdf

Event most basic moments  will be sufficient  for simple motion detection

Ages ago I developed open source project which also calculates moments ( in java )
https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Even simple center of mass would be sufficient  for simple motion detection ( higher order moments are necessary for pattern matching )

Also interesting reading would be on Hu moments